# Wordpress - How to automatically create a child page

Tags: wordpress

My issue is I have is that users create new pages with content and that works well and as intended. What they have to do is add another page, with no content, select the right template and make it the parent of the page that they just created. The 2nd blank page is there as it gives the user viewing the webpage to view the content in a different way then the main page lists it. Is there a way wordpress can automatically add this blank page to these templates?

Here is how the page structure works

Main Page --> Wordpress Page (user created) --> Wordpress Page (Lists the same content as the parent page but in a different format. This is the blank page that the wordpress user creates.)

So is there a way to automatically create that extra subpage or is there a way I can add that code and link to the original wordpress page template?

Thanks,
Ryan

Answer (score 0):

You can add action after publish page. In this action, you can add new page with properties.

You can try this:

```
function on_page_publish( $ID, $post ) {

    $my_post = array(
      'post_title'    => 'My post',
      'post_content'  => 'This is my post.',
      'post_status'   => 'publish',
      'post_author'   => 1,
    );

    // Insert the post into the database
    wp_insert_post( $my_post );

}
add_action(  'publish_page',  'on_page_publish', 10, 2 );
```

Work will be useful to all available here:

```
$post = array(
  'ID'             => [ <post id> ] // Are you updating an existing post?
  'post_content'   => [ <string> ] // The full text of the post.
  'post_name'      => [ <string> ] // The name (slug) for your post
  'post_title'     => [ <string> ] // The title of your post.
  'post_status'    => [ 'draft' | 'publish' | 'pending'| 'future' | 'private' | custom registered status ] // Default 'draft'.
  'post_type'      => [ 'post' | 'page' | 'link' | 'nav_menu_item' | custom post type ] // Default 'post'.
  'post_author'    => [ <user ID> ] // The user ID number of the author. Default is the current user ID.
  'ping_status'    => [ 'closed' | 'open' ] // Pingbacks or trackbacks allowed. Default is the option 'default_ping_status'.
  'post_parent'    => [ <post ID> ] // Sets the parent of the new post, if any. Default 0.
  'menu_order'     => [ <order> ] // If new post is a page, sets the order in which it should appear in supported menus. Default 0.
  'to_ping'        => // Space or carriage return-separated list of URLs to ping. Default empty string.
  'pinged'         => // Space or carriage return-separated list of URLs that have been pinged. Default empty string.
  'post_password'  => [ <string> ] // Password for post, if any. Default empty string.
  'guid'           => // Skip this and let Wordpress handle it, usually.
  'post_content_filtered' => // Skip this and let Wordpress handle it, usually.
  'post_excerpt'   => [ <string> ] // For all your post excerpt needs.
  'post_date'      => [ Y-m-d H:i:s ] // The time post was made.
  'post_date_gmt'  => [ Y-m-d H:i:s ] // The time post was made, in GMT.
  'comment_status' => [ 'closed' | 'open' ] // Default is the option 'default_comment_status', or 'closed'.
  'post_category'  => [ array(<category id>, ...) ] // Default empty.
  'tags_input'     => [ '<tag>, <tag>, ...' | array ] // Default empty.
  'tax_input'      => [ array( <taxonomy> => <array | string> ) ] // For custom taxonomies. Default empty.
  'page_template'  => [ <string> ] // Requires name of template file, eg template.php. Default empty.
);
```